# Logical Equivalence Question - basic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$(p \wedge \neg q) \vee(p \vee\neg q) \Leftrightarrow q\rightarrow p$

I am learning discrete math and I was stuck in this problem for hours.

I tried using De Morgan's law as well as other equivalence laws but I ended up with the same hypothesis.

Is there any advice that I could obtain? Thank you.

Comment: What laws do you have?

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

DeMorgan's Laws are not required.

---

Begin with: $~~~(p\wedge\neg q)\vee(p\vee\neg q)$

Associate to: $~((p\wedge \neg q)\vee p)\vee \neg q$

Commute to: $~\neg q\vee(p\vee(p\wedge\neg q))$

...

End with: $q\to p$

---

All steps are equivalences therefore $((p\wedge\neg q)\vee(p\vee\neg q))\iff (q\to p)$

Comment: Could you please explain how (p∨(p∧¬q)) became p? Thank you.

Comment: Look at your list of [Laws of Logical Equivalences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence#Logical_equivalences).

Answer (score 0):

From $(p\land\lnot q)\lor(p\lor\lnot q)$ we get

$(p\lor(p\lor\lnot q))\land(\lnot q\lor(p\lor\lnot q))$ by distributive law, then

$(p\lor p\lor\lnot q)\land(\lnot q\lor p\lor\lnot q)$ by associativity, then

$(p\lor\lnot q)\land(p\lor\lnot q)$ by idempotency on disjunction, then

$p\lor\lnot q$ by idempotency on conjunction, finally

$q\rightarrow p$ by material implication.

The laws/properties/rules used were all equivalences, so $(p\land\lnot q)\lor(p\lor\lnot q)\Leftrightarrow q\to p$.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use a truth table to find if there is a logical equivalency. However, you should probably try to simplify the left side as (p∧¬q)∨(p∨¬q) is equivalent to (p∨¬q) since any case where (p∧¬q) is true, (p∨¬q) also holds true.